# Adoptable storage questions

Tags: app2sd, link2sd, adoptable-storage

I recently updated to marshmallow with cyanogenmod 13 to use the "adoptable storage" feature. I was disappointed to find out that that only some apps could be put on the adopted storage. I used link2sd in the past as 11gb of internal is insufficient for my 300 apps. However, Link2sd is broken on marshmallow, and I am limited to 11gb once again, so here are my questions:

1. Is there any way to install all apps on the SD card in android marshmallow? Eg. Method to force all apps to adoptable storage, link2sd fix, Cutsom marshmallow rom, etc. (Or am I just doing things wrong)
2. What's the point of adopting the SD as internal storage when not all apps can be moved? I really don't understand how adoptable storage helps anything.

Comment: Just a pointer (not tried myself): [Apps2SD: All in One Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.pricealert.apps2sd) is an alternative to Link2SD you might wish to give a try. And well, I wouldn't use that "adoptable storage" either :)

Comment: It actually worked!.. kind of. The problem with link2sd was that it couldn't create the mount scripts. App2sd created them, but every time I rebooted, the second partition would not be mounted properly. It only gets mounted once I do a soft reboot through app2sd. When its mounted properly, I would receive a notification saying my SD card is corrupted( (which means its mounted priperly)

Comment: So it does work, or just partially? Maybe you can contact the author with the issues you have, and she might be able to fix it? Of course, only after [checking the FAQ](http://www.apps2sd.info/faq.html) ;) If that doesn't work out, there's also [FolderMount](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devasque.fmount).

Comment: It works properly, but every time I boot I have to do a soft boot. The FAQ has my problem: "Some ROMs don't support running commands on boot therefore Apps2SD mounts the 2nd partition after system has finished booting. So you're asked to do a soft reboot." I'll just have to deal with it for now until its fixed. Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

Fix for link2sd:

1. Download [Apps2SD: All in One Tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=in.co.pricealert.apps2sd)
2. Use *Apps2SD: All in One Tool* to create Mount scripts on the second partition.
3. You can now use link2sd normally. You may need to keep *Apps2SD* if you have mount problems on boot.
4. If your linked apps disappear after booting, wait for *Apps2SD* to initialize. It will prompt you to do a soft boot. Click okay, and the second partition should be mounted after soft booting. Your apps will be restored and you can use link2sd again. (You need to do this every time you reboot)

Comment: Note on my edit: Your naming of the app might have caused confusion, as there are plenty of apps called ***App2SD*** (note the extra S in *App_s_2SD* here).

Answer (score 0):

Use partition tool to get rid of SD card corrupt error.  Use exFAT file system for partition 1 for SD card to be recognized by the phone.  Use ext4 file system for partition 2 for apps2sd app to link/unlink apps to SD card.

If you plan on downloading from YouTube a lot, give yourself appropriate size storage because it only recognizes SDcard recognized by your phone even if YouTube is linked to SD card by apps2sd.